# Postgresql: Select query on view returning no records

Tags: postgresql, select, view, user-permissions

I have a view named vw_check_space in my public schema (using postgresql 9.4). When I run a

```
select * from public.vw_check_space;
```

as a postgres user, I get a list of rows but when I run the same query by another user 'user1', it returns nothing.

View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.vw_check_space AS 
WITH constants AS (
     SELECT current_setting('block_size'::text)::numeric AS bs,
        23 AS hdr,
        8 AS ma
    ), no_stats AS (
     SELECT columns.table_schema,
        columns.table_name,
        psut.n_live_tup::numeric AS est_rows,
        pg_table_size(psut.relid::regclass)::numeric AS table_size
       FROM columns
         JOIN pg_stat_user_tables psut ON columns.table_schema::name = psut.schemaname AND columns.table_name::name = psut.relname
         LEFT JOIN pg_stats ON columns.table_schema::name = pg_stats.schemaname AND columns.table_name::name = pg_stats.tablename AND columns.column_name::name = pg_stats.attname
      WHERE pg_stats.attname IS NULL AND (columns.table_schema::text <> ALL (ARRAY['pg_catalog'::character varying, 'information_schema'::character varying]::text[]))
      GROUP BY columns.table_schema, columns.table_name, psut.relid, psut.n_live_tup
    ), null_headers AS (
     SELECT constants.hdr + 1 + sum(
            CASE
                WHEN pg_stats.null_frac <> 0::double precision THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) / 8 AS nullhdr,
        sum((1::double precision - pg_stats.null_frac) * pg_stats.avg_width::double precision) AS datawidth,
        max(pg_stats.null_frac) AS maxfracsum,
        pg_stats.schemaname,
        pg_stats.tablename,
        constants.hdr,
        constants.ma,
        constants.bs
       FROM pg_stats
         CROSS JOIN constants
         LEFT JOIN no_stats ON pg_stats.schemaname = no_stats.table_schema::name AND pg_stats.tablename = no_stats.table_name::name
      WHERE (pg_stats.schemaname <> ALL (ARRAY['pg_catalog'::name, 'information_schema'::name])) AND no_stats.table_name IS NULL AND (EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM columns
              WHERE pg_stats.schemaname = columns.table_schema::name AND pg_stats.tablename = columns.table_name::name))
      GROUP BY pg_stats.schemaname, pg_stats.tablename, constants.hdr, constants.ma, constants.bs
    ), data_headers AS (
     SELECT null_headers.ma,
        null_headers.bs,
        null_headers.hdr,
        null_headers.schemaname,
        null_headers.tablename,
        (null_headers.datawidth + (null_headers.hdr + null_headers.ma -
            CASE
                WHEN (null_headers.hdr % null_headers.ma) = 0 THEN null_headers.ma
                ELSE null_headers.hdr % null_headers.ma
            END)::double precision)::numeric AS datahdr,
        null_headers.maxfracsum * (null_headers.nullhdr + null_headers.ma -
            CASE
                WHEN (null_headers.nullhdr % null_headers.ma::bigint) = 0 THEN null_headers.ma::bigint
                ELSE null_headers.nullhdr % null_headers.ma::bigint
            END)::double precision AS nullhdr2
       FROM null_headers
    ), table_estimates AS (
     SELECT data_headers.schemaname,
        data_headers.tablename,
        data_headers.bs,
        pg_class.reltuples::numeric AS est_rows,
        pg_class.relpages::numeric * data_headers.bs AS table_bytes,
        ceil(pg_class.reltuples * (data_headers.datahdr::double precision + data_headers.nullhdr2 + 4::double precision + data_headers.ma::double precision -
            CASE
                WHEN (data_headers.datahdr % data_headers.ma::numeric) = 0::numeric THEN data_headers.ma::numeric
                ELSE data_headers.datahdr % data_headers.ma::numeric
            END::double precision) / (data_headers.bs - 20::numeric)::double precision) * data_headers.bs::double precision AS expected_bytes,
        pg_class.reltoastrelid
       FROM data_headers
         JOIN pg_class ON data_headers.tablename = pg_class.relname
         JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid AND data_headers.schemaname = pg_namespace.nspname
      WHERE pg_class.relkind = 'r'::"char"
    ), estimates_with_toast AS (
     SELECT table_estimates.schemaname,
        table_estimates.tablename,
        true AS can_estimate,
        table_estimates.est_rows,
        table_estimates.table_bytes + COALESCE(toast.relpages, 0)::numeric * table_estimates.bs AS table_bytes,
        table_estimates.expected_bytes + ceil(COALESCE(toast.reltuples, 0::real) / 4::double precision) * table_estimates.bs::double precision AS expected_bytes
       FROM table_estimates
         LEFT JOIN pg_class toast ON table_estimates.reltoastrelid = toast.oid AND toast.relkind = 't'::"char"
    ), table_estimates_plus AS (
     SELECT current_database() AS databasename,
        estimates_with_toast.schemaname,
        estimates_with_toast.tablename,
        estimates_with_toast.can_estimate,
        estimates_with_toast.est_rows,
            CASE
                WHEN estimates_with_toast.table_bytes > 0::numeric THEN estimates_with_toast.table_bytes
                ELSE NULL::numeric
            END AS table_bytes,
            CASE
                WHEN estimates_with_toast.expected_bytes > 0::double precision THEN estimates_with_toast.expected_bytes::numeric
                ELSE NULL::numeric
            END AS expected_bytes,
            CASE
                WHEN estimates_with_toast.expected_bytes > 0::double precision AND estimates_with_toast.table_bytes > 0::numeric AND estimates_with_toast.expected_bytes <= estimates_with_toast.table_bytes::double precision THEN (estimates_with_toast.table_bytes::double precision - estimates_with_toast.expected_bytes)::numeric
                ELSE 0::numeric
            END AS bloat_bytes
       FROM estimates_with_toast
    UNION ALL
     SELECT current_database() AS databasename,
        no_stats.table_schema,
        no_stats.table_name,
        false AS bool,
        no_stats.est_rows,
        no_stats.table_size,
        NULL::numeric AS "numeric",
        NULL::numeric AS "numeric"
       FROM no_stats
    ), bloat_data AS (
     SELECT current_database() AS databasename,
        table_estimates_plus.schemaname,
        table_estimates_plus.tablename,
        table_estimates_plus.can_estimate,
        table_estimates_plus.table_bytes,
        round(table_estimates_plus.table_bytes / (1024::double precision ^ 2::double precision)::numeric, 3) AS table_mb,
        table_estimates_plus.expected_bytes,
        round(table_estimates_plus.expected_bytes / (1024::double precision ^ 2::double precision)::numeric, 3) AS expected_mb,
        round(table_estimates_plus.bloat_bytes * 100::numeric / table_estimates_plus.table_bytes) AS pct_bloat,
        round(table_estimates_plus.bloat_bytes / (1024::numeric ^ 2::numeric), 2) AS mb_bloat,
        table_estimates_plus.est_rows
       FROM table_estimates_plus
    )
SELECT bloat_data.databasename,
bloat_data.schemaname,
bloat_data.tablename,
bloat_data.can_estimate,
bloat_data.table_bytes,
bloat_data.table_mb,
bloat_data.expected_bytes,
bloat_data.expected_mb,
bloat_data.pct_bloat,
bloat_data.mb_bloat,
bloat_data.est_rows
   FROM bloat_data
  ORDER BY bloat_data.pct_bloat DESC;
```

I have provided connect privilege to the database and grant usage and select privilege to user user1. I am not sure what other privileges I would be missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I have also provided usage and select privilege to the tables and schema the view is using during its creation.

Comment: start with view definition, eg `where 'postgres' = current_user()` would already lead to no rows returned. also could be row security. but start with postgres version and view definition please

Comment: I am using postgres 9.4 and have included the view definition

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/view-pg-stats.html

> The view pg_stats provides access to the information stored in the
>   pg_statistic catalog. This view allows access only to rows of
>   pg_statistic that correspond to tables the user has permission to
>   read, and therefore it is safe to allow public read access to this
>   view.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/monitoring-stats.html

> pg_stat_user_tables   Same as pg_stat_all_tables, except that only user
>   tables are shown.

so after you grant read on other owner tables to user, you still join `pg_stat_user_tables` which will cut list to only those tables onwer of which you are... - either exclude it from view, or use `left outer join` instead of `inner join`

I'm talking about `JOIN pg_stat_user_tables`, but you should check every table you join and read about all views you include in your query

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I created a function as a postgres user that does exactly the same as what the view is doing and made it executable by all. So now when my user user1 does select on it, I can now successfully see the result I expected to see in the first place.

Comment: that's correct. i made the function security definer and it worked :)